# Complex select - states and counties

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting this complicated select to work for me.

Here is a graphic of my structure.
http://www.bandwise.com/files/tester_db.png

SQL file of the structure and sampe data.
http://www.bandwise.com/files/tester_db.sql

To put is simply, I have a table called "leases" and one called "apartments." There is a one to many relationship between leases and apartments. Apartments identify a U.S. state and county in which they belong. Therefore, a given lease may have many apartments scattered across the country.

What I need to do is select ONLY U.S. states which contain one or more apartments and return a count of how many leases apply. Because some leases may have apartments in multiple states, a lease may need to be counted in multiple states.

Here is a test query that I'm working with.

```
SET @timenow = 1360855314;

SELECT l.lid, c.aid, c.leaseid, c.serialnum, c.state, c.county
FROM leases l, apartments c
WHERE c.leaseid = l.lid
    AND l.closebidding > @timenow AND l.status = 1;
```

I can see here that I have 6 leases in state #1 (Texas) and 2 leases in state #2 (Louisiana). How do I go about querying from the states table outward to get the number of leases based on where their apartments are located?

The return should look like this.

```
---------------------------
|  state      |   total   |
---------------------------
|  Texas      |     6     |
---------------------------
|  Louisiana  |     3     |
---------------------------
```

Comment: Is that part of the WHERE clause on line 6?

Comment: Wrong, my mistake. Null never works because you always recive a 0. Maybe if use WHERE s.stateid = s2.stateid AND s2.dateadded > [unix timestamp] and s2.TOTAL <> 0 works.

Comment: Great. :) I put the answer so you can mark as correct and make this question answered

Comment: I realize it has been a while since I asked this question, but I was asked to review the website functions using this and discovered that it wasn't working after all. I have amended the question to include much more detail about what I am trying to do and some sample data.

Comment: I can see sample results but no sample data.

Comment: @ypercube if you were in the Heap you would've. We made him a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `count(distinct l.lid)`:

```
SELECT s.state_name,count(distinct l.lid) 
FROM 
  leases l
  JOIN apartments c ON c.leaseid = l.lid
  JOIN states s ON s.state_id = c.state
WHERE
  l.closebidding > @timenow AND l.status = 1 
GROUP BY s.state_name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b275/13)

Comment: You could even skip the join to `leases` and use `count(distinct c.leaseid)`, if `apartments.leaseid` cannot be Null.

Comment: @ypercube Good call, you're right... I'll update the answer with that suggestion.

Comment: @ypercube Oh wait... there's the filters in the `where` against columns in `leases`... so I think it's needed for that reason.

Comment: So far, this looks good. I'm going to run these in my live system and see if all is working. If I can't find any issues, I'll be back to accept your answer later today, Michael. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
WHERE s.stateid = s2.stateid AND s2.dateadded > [unix timestamp] and s2.TOTAL <> 0
```